# Regular expression for python syntax

Tags: python, syntax

I want to write a python code generator, and it would be helpful if I had the regular expression that describes all valid python programs.

Does such a regular expression exist? What is it?

Comment: A regular expression? WHY? What are you trying to accomplish with that? It sounds like a truly awful idea, and most probably impossible.

Comment: As others have said, regular expressions are not sufficient to describes python syntax.  However, the relatively short grammar that describes them can be seen in the source code here http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/d7bed032520b/Grammar/Grammar

Answer (score 11):

Such a regular expression cannot exist, because regular expressions are, by definition, not powerful enough to recognize Turing complete languages (such as python).

Comment: My + 1.  For example, regular expressions cannot be used to accept the nested pair structures -- like nested parentheses in expressions.

Answer (score 5):

If you generate a string with fragment of a Python code, and you want to check whether it is syntactically correct, try the built-in function [`compile`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#compile).  It returns the resulting code object or it raises the `SyntaxError` exception.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29) your code. There are a couple of tools to do that with Python; [pylint](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylint), [PyChecker](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyChecker) and [pyflakes](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes) should all do the trick.

To answer your actual question: no, this is not a job for regular expressions.